# Downlaod all apt package dependencies for specific package to install later on another machine with different architecture and no Internet

Tags: apt, software-installation, aptitude

I have arm64 devices running ubuntu 20.04. This device does not have Internet connection. I want to install `upower` utility on it. So I was thinking to offline download all packages required to install on this machine on my laptop which runs ubuntu 20.04 x86_64.

I tried following:

```
~$ cd Downloads
~/Downloads$ mkdir upower-packages
~/Downloads$ cd upower-packages
~/Downloads/upower-packages$ sudo apt-get update
~/Downloads/upower-packages$ apt-get --download-only -o Dir::Cache::archives=./ -o Debug::NoLocking=1 --print-uris install upower:arm64
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package upower:arm64
```

So I tried adding arm64 archtecture, but :

```
~/Downloads/upower-packages$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture arm64
~/Downloads/upower-packages$ sudo apt-get update
~/Downloads/upower-packages$ apt-get --download-only -o Dir::Cache::archives=./ -o Debug::NoLocking=1 --print-uris install upower:arm64
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package upower:arm64
```

However the package is indeed available for arm64 as can be seen at [this link](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/arm64/upower/download). I also tried installing it on another arm machine running ubuntu 20.04 with the Internet with simple `apt-get install upower` and it worked.

What I am missing here?

Comment: The usual mirrors don't have ARM packages. You have to add the ports repository for that: http://ports.ubuntu.com/